# Which database is better for Bilingual Dictionary Mobile IOS App ?

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c, dictionary

I am new to IOS development.
I am going to make a Bilingual Dictionary App for IOS. I have two options in front of me for choosing database. SQLlite and MySQL.

If I choose SQLLite then I believe I will have to pack the database with the app. Every user who will use this app the database will be downloaded to his device.

is it a good approach ?

or I should use MySQL ? that stays on the server and app will connect back and forth to get data from it.

Please guide which database should I use for Bilingual Dictionary Mobile app ?
Or If there is anything else I am missing ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You don't have two options... SQLlite and MySQL are two completely different things.  SQLlite is an on-device database and MySQL is a server-hosted database.  The discussion isn't about what database to use... and arguably, you should probably be using SQLlite either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are advantages and disadvantages to each, depending on the functionality and user experience you prefer.  Unless you plan to update the content frequently, you wouldn't expect it to change constantly, so there isn't an essential need to provide dynamic content.  However, hosting the content online can save a lot of space, which for some mobile users may be limited.

However, *to me the most important factor to consider* is that as a bilingual dictionary, you may have a substantial market of people who are travelling.  People who are travelling often don't have data service, and thus must rely on wifi if they want to access this dictionary. As someone who travels with my cellphone, having a dictionary which does not require a data connection is a major functional advantage, and as a designer I would want to provide this functionality, even if just as an option. This may change if you expect that the greater part of your market is not going to use it while travelling.

Comment: Thanks for replying ! What I am thinking if I use sqllite then there will so many copies of database on multiple devices. on the other hand it will give user more control when he s offline. I think I am going to use My SQL. one it will prevent multiple copies of my database. two) I will be able to update it later.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Mitch Goshorn's answer. I don't know if you're worrying about the "security" of your database or you just want to save space on device. But I suggest the local one (SQLite). In case that you don't want user to steel your database by hijacking the application folder, you may want to think about encryption. Sorry if this is not considered to be an answer cause I don't have enough reputation to comment.